# React: using state in a passed callback function to a class constructor doesnt use latest version of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

Sorry for the confusing title, but here is what is going on:

In `MyComponent`, I am setting a `count` state with the `useState` React hook.
Once the component mounts (ie. `useEffect` with no dependencies), I am instantiaitng two `MyClass` objects with the first argument as a callback function that increments the state, and the second argument is the `timeOut` period to call the callback function.

The first instance of `MyClass` calls the callback in 1000 ms and sets the new value for `count`, which once updated, is logged in the second `useEffect`.

However, when the second instance of `MyClass` calls the call back (after `timeOut` period of 3000 ms), and tries incrementing the `count` value, it uses the state of `count` from when the `MyClass` was instantiated (which was 0), so it increments `count` to 1 (wanted behavior is to increment to 2, since the first instance of `MyClass` already incremented `count` from 0 to 1)

This is not an issue related to the asynchronicity behavior of `setState` because it is evident that that first update to `count` happens before the second instance tries to update it again (the second `useEffect` gets called when `count` state is updated, which from the console log messages you can see is happening before second instance of `MyClass` calls the call back).

***JSFiddle link:*** https://jsfiddle.net/hfv24dpL/

So in conclusion, I think that the issue is that the `count` state in the callback function is a copy of the `count` state at the time when the callback functions were passed to the `MyClass` constructor.

A solution to this example could be to just instantiate the second instance of `MyClass` when the `count` state is updated (in the second `useEffect`), but this is not the solution I am looking for.

Another solution is to use `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)` to increment `count`, but this isnt viable in my real application (`MyComponent` and `MyClass` are a skeleton example of my real React application that I wrote just for this question).

I want to be able to instantiate the classes togethor when component mounts (in first `useEffect`), and have the callbacks refer to the most updated version of `count`.

Is there a solution for this ^ or is there no way around this javascript and React implementation? Thanks for reading all this, I know its long :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

class MyClass{

  constructor(callback, timeOut){

    // call callback in timeOut milliseconds
    this.timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();

      }, timeOut)

  }

  clearTimeOut(){

    clearTimeout(this.timeOutId);

  }

}


function MyComponent(){

  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // component did mount
  useEffect(() => {
    let myClass1 = new MyClass(funcToCallback, 1000);
    let myClass2 = new MyClass(funcToCallback, 3000);

    // when component unmounts, clear the timeouts of MyClass instances
    return () => {

      myClass1.clearTimeOut();
      myClass2.clearTimeOut();

    }
  }, []);


  // counter state updated
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("COUNT UPDATED TO: ", count);

  }, [count])

  // get counter and increment it by 1
  function funcToCallback(){

    console.log("CALLBACK CALLED");
    let newCount = count + 1;
    incCount(newCount);

  }

  function incCount(newCount){

    console.log("NEW COUNT: ", newCount);
    setCount(newCount);

  }

  return (
    <div>
      COUNT: { count }
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Excellent first question!

Answer (score 3):

The `funcToCallback` that gets used is the one in the initial mount of the component, when `count` is 0. Variables declared with `const` don't change, and the `useEffect` callback only gets called once, the `count` that the `funcToCallback` closes over remains at 0 forever.

Easiest fix would be to use the function version of the setter instead, which will give you the prior state as an argument - then you can just increment it. Change

```
  function incCount(newCount){
    console.log("NEW COUNT: ", newCount);
    setCount(newCount);
  }
```

to

```
  function incCount(){
    setCount((lastCount) => {
      console.log("NEW COUNT: ", (lastCount + 1));
      return lastCount + 1;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello Jonas, thanks for sharing! Yes I am aware of the closure issue, and I provided the same answer as you did near the end of my post, however I am looking for another solution, because the function version of useState isnt a viable solution in my actual application. (I wrote this code as an example of the closure issue, my application deals with the closure issue but in a different context).